# Accessing services in UI-Router's `otherwise` function

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

In UI-Router's `RootModule.otherwise` we can specify where to redirect the user if the user is opening a URL that the application doesn't recognize. I have been using the simple format, just a string specifying the target state's name:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [UIRouterModule.forRoot({
        states: [
            {
                name: "home",
                url: "/home",
                component: HomeComponent
            }
        ],
        otherwise: "/home"
    })],
    exports: [UIRouterModule],
    providers: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

But now I need to get data by calling a service to determine which target state I should redirect the user. I tried the function format of the `otherwise` hoping to be able to get access to my service through the injector:

```
otherwise: (matchValue, url: UrlParts, router: UIRouter) => {
    // this didn't work, router.globals.transition is not available
    const userPrefSvc = router.globals.transition.injector().get(UserPreferenceService);
}
```

But it didn't work, I can't find a way to get hold of the injector.

Is it possible to access services from the `otherwise` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is actually from [Christopher Thielen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3225368/chris-t).

Setting the `otherwise` function can also be done in config function, where we have access to injector:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [UIRouterModule.forRoot({
        states: [
            {
                name: "home",
                url: "/home",
                component: HomeComponent
            }
        ],
        config: (uiRouter: UIRouter, injector: Injector, statesModule: StatesModule) => {
            let userPrefSvc = injector.get(UserPreferenceService);

            uiRouter.urlService.rules.otherwise((matchValue, url, router) => {
                // ...
                router.stateService.go("home");
                // or
                return "/home";
            });
        }
    })],
    exports: [UIRouterModule],
    providers: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```